# Retrieve data in double and Int using intent in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to get the data using intent in kotlin but it is giving an error `No value passed for parameter 'defaultValue'`. The data of string data is not giving an error but the double and Int are.

```
class ProductActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   
companion object {
    const val KEY_TITLE = "title"
    const val KEY_PRICE = "price"
    const val KEY_IMAGE = "image"
    const val KEY_CATEGORY = "category"
   }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val title = intent
    title.getStringExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_TITLE)

    val price = intent
    price.getDoubleExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_PRICE) -> error "No value passed for parameter defaultValue"

    val category = intent
    category.getStringExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_CATEGORY)

    val image = intent
    image.getIntExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_IMAGE) -> error "No value passed for parameter defaultValue"


  private fun startProductActivity(productItem: ProductItem) {

    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,ProductActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_TITLE,"title")
    intent.putExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_PRICE,"price")
    intent.putExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_IMAGE,"image")
    intent.putExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_CATEGORY,"category")

    startActivity(intent)
 }
}
```

I dont know why the reason behind this behavior. I have tried but none solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're encountering is because you're missing the defaultValue parameter when calling getDoubleExtra and getIntExtra methods. These methods have an optional defaultValue parameter that specifies the value to return if no value is found for the given key.

```
val price = intent.getDoubleExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_PRICE, 0.0) 


val image = intent.getIntExtra(ProductActivity.KEY_IMAGE, 0)
```